# jQuery script not working on html appended from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've already referred to these answers but that doesn't solve:

[jQuery on button click not working after append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977821/jquery-on-button-click-not-working-after-append)

[Jquery click event not working after append method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420558/jquery-click-event-not-working-after-append-method)

I want to load the html for click button on page load like this:(this shows the html with css correctly, but the script is not working)

```
$.get( "/plugins/system/conversekit/conver/test.php", function( data ) {
       $('body').append(data);
    }, "html" );
```

But if I load the html i n this way the script works:

```
$('body').append('<div id="ckit" class="layout-compact is-hiddenx"\
     data-ckit-compact style=""><a href="javascript:void(0);"\
      class="btn-toggle-ckit" data-ckit-toggle-on><i class="fa fa-comment-o">\
      </i></a></div><div id="ckit" class="layout-full is-hidden disable-scrolling" data-ckit-full>\
      <iframe src="/plugins/system/conver/conver/full-view-contact.php" data-ckit-iframe id="ckit-full-view" \
      name="ckit-full-view" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"allowtransparency="true" \
      style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; padding: 0px; \
      margin: 0px; float: none; background: none;"></iframe></div>');
```

SCRIPT:

```
var toggleCkitOn = $('[data-ckit-toggle-on]');
 toggleCkitOn.on('click', function(e) {
            $(ckitFull).removeClass("is-hidden");
            $(ckitCompact).addClass("is-hidden");
            $('body').addClass("disable-scrolling");
            $("html").css({"height": "100%", "overflow": "hidden"});
            $("body").css({"position": "relative"});
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

HTML

```
<div id="ckit" class="layout-compact is-hiddenx" data-ckit-compact style="">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-toggle-ckit" data-ckit-toggle-on><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i></a>
</div>

<div id="ckit" class="layout-full is-hidden disable-scrolling" data-ckit-full>
    <iframe src="conver/full-view-contact.php" data-ckit-iframe id="ckit-full-view" name="ckit-full-view" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; float: none; background: none;"></iframe>
</div>
```

I tried to avoid the delegation but doesn't help,

```
$('body').on('click',toggleCkitOn, function(e) {...});
```

Tried with other promises to check if ajax functions correctly, and I get all the below get executed without error:

**1) success
2) second success
3) finished**

```
 var jqxhr = $.get( "/plugins/system/conversekit/conversekit/test.php", function() {
          alert( "success" );
        })
          .done(function() {
            alert( "second success" );
          })
          .fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
          })
          .always(function() {
            alert( "finished" );
          });
```

[image]

Working answer (but i want the variables to be global scope, declaring them outside this function makes the click the doesn't work):

```
$("body").on("click", ".btn-toggle-ckit", function(e) { 
            var toggleCkitOn = $('[data-ckit-toggle-on]');
            var ckitFull = $('[data-ckit-full]');
            var ckitCompact = $('[data-ckit-compact]');
            var ckitIframe = $('[data-ckit-iframe]');
             $(ckitFull).removeClass("is-hidden");
             $(ckitCompact).addClass("is-hidden");
             $('body').addClass("disable-scrolling");
             $("html").css({"height": "100%", "overflow": "hidden"});
             $("body").css({"position": "relative"});
             e.preventDefault();
        } );
```

Comment: Did you check if you imported a Jquery lib?

Comment: are you sure the AJAX process into PHP files was loaded successfully? I think, your problem is in there..

Comment: Where do you define the script?

Comment: @Kode.Error404, yes the jquery is imported

Comment: The script is an external folder, the path is correctly specified and its imported as its found in source code

Comment: the test .php only contains html content and its loaded that why I could see the element loaded @FadhlyPermata

Comment: Then maybe show this in the jsfiddle

Comment: try put your delegation code into function, and then call the function each you call AJAX process.. maybe your delegation was failed, because the object is not found on DOM

Comment: @FadhlyPermata, I don't quite understand how to do that, could you show me please?

Comment: @Keren sorry the fiddle contains too much errors. Maybe show us the link to your site instead

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy, I'm developing in localhost

Comment: try my answer.. @Keren

Comment: @Keren did using $('a.btn-toggle-ckit') give the same result instead $('[data-ckit-toggle-on]')?

Comment: @FadhlyPermata, yes but I prefer to use the html5 data attribute

Comment: so i would use $('[data-ckit-toggle-on]') instead

Comment: I mean, have you used the $('a.btn-toggle-ckit') and store it into var? the value is in the right portion?

Comment: No didn't use $('a.btn-toggle-ckit')

Answer (score 0):

```
function ckitDelegate() {
var toggleCkitOn = $('[data-ckit-toggle-on]');
 toggleCkitOn.on('click', function(e) {
            $(ckitFull).removeClass("is-hidden");
            $(ckitCompact).addClass("is-hidden");
            $('body').addClass("disable-scrolling");
            $("html").css({"height": "100%", "overflow": "hidden"});
            $("body").css({"position": "relative"});
            e.preventDefault();
        });
};

$.get("/plugins/system/conversekit/conver/test.php", function( data ) {
       $('body').append(data);
       ckitDelegate();
}, "html").fail(function() {
alert( "error" );
});
```

**This my last opinion**, i will give-up if it not working too:

```
$.get("/plugins/system/conversekit/conver/test.php", function( data ) {
  $('body').append(data);
  setTimeout(function(){ ckitDelegate(); }, 500);
}, "html");
```

Comment: I am not sure what the `$("html").css({"height": "100%", "overflow": "hidden"});` purposes... So, I am still put in there too..

Comment: Tried your way, still the script doesn't work...btw the $('html').css... is to expand the div to the full height

Comment: the ckitDelegate() is not get called

Comment: if so, the `get` method not loaded properlly.. have you try the other promise except success? as referred from here [https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: Please check my post, as I tried with other promises and it seems like my get request works

Comment: Tried your updated answer, still the same ,s cript doesn't work

Comment: @Keren your welcome, and pardon me can help you out of this problem

Answer (score 0):

please try this. Add click event in one function and call that function on DOM load and after the append operation. Like this:

```
  function Init(){
 toggleCkitOn.on('click', function(e) {});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
Init();
});

$.get( "/plugins/system/conversekit/conver/test.php", function( data ) {
       $('body').append(data);
    Init();
    }, "html" );
```

> Just make sure you have defined the Init() before calling them

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was that the iframe was hiding $('[data-ckit-toggle-on]') and therefore preventing any click events - i.e. the click events weren't firing because you were clicking the iframe, not the a href.

If you remove the iframe (temporarily - solve one issue at a time), then try again, it should at least fire the click event.

Right click on your $('[data-ckit-toggle-on]') element in the DOM then click "Inspect element" to see if it is visible or not.

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
$.get("plugins/system/conversekit/conver/test.php",
    function(data) { $('body').append(data); },
        "html").then(function(data) {
        var toggleCkitOn = $('[data-ckit-toggle-on]');
        var ckitFull = $('[data-ckit-full]');
        var ckitCompact = $('[data-ckit-compact]');
        var ckitIframe = $('[data-ckit-iframe]');

        $("body").on("click", ".btn-toggle-ckit", function(e) { 
            alert("hi");
             $(ckitFull).removeClass("is-hidden");
             $(ckitCompact).addClass("is-hidden");
             $('body').addClass("disable-scrolling");
             $("html").css({"height": "100%", "overflow": "hidden"});
             $("body").css({"position": "relative"});
             e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

If you're still having trouble clicking the a href, try adding a css margin-top to the iframe to where it isn't covering the a href. Let me know.

Comment: @Biblo, yes the element shows up when inspect with and without the iframe.. Also after removing the iframe, script doesn't work fro simple alert('hi); on click event..But with my new solution it works, so I would like to know the way to deal with the variable scope as I mentioned..please see if you could help..thanks

Comment: The element might be showing up but still be hidden by the iframe. I'll look into it.

Comment: Edited post - give it a shot and let me know if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments. Regarding your scope issue, you won't be able to access your ckit elements globally until after the $.get is finished. Your best bet is to use a .then (like my solution above) and access them in subsequently called functions.

Comment: unortunately I can't do it your way because, my get call need to be seperated from the events handling script for some purposes, meaning in two different files

Comment: It's possible to transfer the variables between the two files. Could you provide more information as to why this won't work?

Answer (score 0):

If your html create dynamic that time you should bind click method.

Write this code after appending your html.

Example :-

```
$('#buttonOuter').append('<input type="button" id="myid"/>');

$("#myid").unbind();
if($("#myid").length > 0 && $._data( $("#myid")[0], "events" )==undefined){
    $('#myid').bind('click',function(){
        // write your code
    });
}
```

I think it's working for you